# Android GridLayout span behaviour different when changed programmatically

Tags: android, html

I have a XML GridLayout where one cell should span over two cells without affecting the other cells in the grid. I can do this within the XML layout file with this setting

```
<!-- ROW ONE -->
<include layout= "@layout/tile"
    android:id="@+id/tile11"
    grid:layout_row="0"
    grid:layout_column="0"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill"/>
<include layout= "@layout/tile"
    android:id="@+id/tile12"
    grid:layout_row="0"
    grid:layout_column="1"
    grid:layout_columnSpan="2"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill"/>
<include layout= "@layout/tile"
    android:id="@+id/tile14"
    grid:layout_row="0"
    grid:layout_column="3"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill"/>
```

and this how it looks like and should look like
[GridLayout from XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0iGs.png)

BUT i want to change the arrangement of the cells dynamically within the code. This is how i try to get the same result programmatically:

```
        tile = (FrameLayout) gridLayout.findViewById(R.id.tile12);
    ((GridLayout.LayoutParams) tile.getLayoutParams()).columnSpec =
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 2f);
```

but the behavior is pretty different.. it messes up my layout and it looks like this (all second columns are affected and a bit wider and the third cell in the first row is just blank instead of covered by the second):

[GridLayout changed programmatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYlaQ.png)

am i diong something wrong or is this a bug with the GridLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... I found the solution myself...
have to use this method:

```
static GridLayout.Spec  spec(int start, int size, float weight)
```

instead .. so the code looks like

```
tile = (FrameLayout) gridLayout.findViewById(R.id.tile12);
((GridLayout.LayoutParams) tile.getLayoutParams()).columnSpec =
        GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 2, 2f);
```

and than the behaviour is the same as defined in XML Layout